# React Native AwesomeProject build failure

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Xcode newb here: Attempting to build AwesomeProject the React Native demo and getting four errors of this sort:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor issue
Expected ':'

../AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTSparseArray.h:14:80: Expected ':'

OS X 10.9.3
XCode 5.1.1
```

I had to auto-fix two __bridge cast issues and there are three Sematic Issue errors

```
Undeclared selector 'set CompletionWithItemsHandler'

(2x) Property 'comletionWithItemsHandler' not found on objec of type 
'UIActivityViewController *'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you somehow running it as an iOS7 app? `completionWithItemsHandler` is only available on iOS8 I believe.

Comment: Looks like it was an XCode version issue. Went to 6.2, highest possible on 10.9.5. Not marking this as the answer as I also reinstalled the entire react-native package and am running a different example so I'm mostly still in the dark.